# Using Internationalization (i18n), shows expression instead of value when application is reloaded

Tags: angularjs

In our application we are using Internationalization (i18n) of angularJs, it works fine when application is loaded but when the application is reloaded or refreshed it starts showing expression instead of value.

for an instance -

- if localization for **Key: '*WRITTENBY*' is value 'WrittenBy'**   then for html code below

  - {{ 'WRITTENBY' | i18n }} Author

the behavior of following html code on page load is proper value for key *WriitenBy*

***WrittenBy Author***

- but on reloading the same page or refreshing, following *expression is rendered instead of the value for Key used*.

***{{ 'WRITTENBY' | i18n }} Author***

Is it any issue with angularJs or some thing has to be taken care of while using i18n(Internationalization) in the code?

Any help is welcome..

Comment: In my experience, this usually means AngularJS threw an error at some point. Keep the console open when you refresh the page, does anything pop up?

Comment: Yes, tried with console open and there are no errors in Console neither any pop up